# Reading INI file with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ini

I'm using Visual Basic to read a file which has frequently-used information. Specifically, my file contains information like this:

```
[Smith]
Name=Sam Smith
Email=sam.smith@yahoo.com
Project=Smith's Treehouse Project
Greeting=Hi Sam,

[Jones]
Name=Josh Jones
Email=josh.jones@gmail.com
Project=Jone's Second-Story Remodel
Greeting=Hi Josh,
```

I'm then trying to read the info into a simple VB command (actually using Dragon Naturally Speaking, but that shouldn't matter) to send an email in Microsoft Outlook.  I don't need to write to the file, or change the values.  I just need to read the info, so I can send the email address to the address field, the project name to the subject field, etc. through the use of List Variables.

How do I write a function to read from the file?

I've spent about 4 hours looking for answers here and on other sites, but am confused.  (I'm obviously brand new to VB.) It seems like every time I find code that looks kind of close, it uses unique coding functions, so I don't know what the right one is.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Where are you writing the code from?  Are you sure this is VB.Net?

Comment: If there's anything in my answer you find unclear, or there's something you'd like a better explanation of just let me know and I'll try to make things clearer. :)

Comment: Hi there! I haven't heard from you in a couple of days. How is this going for you? I'd like to help if you're still having problems with this.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but here's a class that utilizes [**Regular Expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the INI:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public NotInheritable Class IniParser
    Private Shared SectionRegex As New Regex("\[(?<section>[^\n\[\]]+)\]\n*(?<valuelist>(.(?!\[[^\n\[\]]+\]))*)", RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.Compiled)
    Private Shared ValueRegex As New Regex("(?<valuename>[^=\n]+)=(?<value>[^\n]*)", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Parses an .ini-file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="FileName">The path to the file to parse.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function ParseFile(ByVal FileName As String) As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Return IniParser.Parse(File.ReadAllText(FileName))
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Parses a text of .ini-format.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Data">The text to parse.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function Parse(ByVal Data As String) As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Dim Result As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) '(Section, (Value name, Value))
        Dim Sections As MatchCollection = SectionRegex.Matches(Data)

        'Iterate each section.
        For Each SectionMatch As Match In Sections
            Dim Section As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            Dim SectionName As String = SectionMatch.Groups("section").Value
            Dim Values As MatchCollection = ValueRegex.Matches(SectionMatch.Groups("valuelist").Value)

            If Result.ContainsKey(SectionName) = True Then
                'A section by this name already exists.
                Dim i As Integer = 1

                'Append a number to the section name until a unique name is found.
                While Result.ContainsKey(SectionName & i)
                    i += 1
                End While

                Result.Add(SectionName & i, Section)
            Else
                'A section by this name does not exist.
                Result.Add(SectionName, Section)
            End If

            'Iterate each value of this section.
            For Each ValueMatch As Match In Values
                Dim ValueName As String = ValueMatch.Groups("valuename").Value
                Dim Value As String = ValueMatch.Groups("value").Value

                If Section.ContainsKey(ValueName) = True Then
                    'A value by this name already exists.
                    Dim i As Integer = 1

                    'Append a number to the value name until a unique name is found.
                    While Section.ContainsKey(ValueName & i)
                        i += 1
                    End While

                    Section.Add(ValueName & i, Value)
                Else
                    'A value by this name does not exist.
                    Section.Add(ValueName, Value)
                End If
            Next
        Next

        Return Result
    End Function
End Class
```

---

### Example usage

- Reading values in general:

  ```
  Dim IniContents As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) = IniParser.ParseFile("C:\path\to\your\file\here.ini")

  For Each SectionName As String In IniContents.Keys
      For Each ValueName As String In IniContents(SectionName).Keys
          Dim Value As String = IniContents(SectionName)(ValueName)

          '[SectionName]
          'ValueName=Value
          'ValueName=Value
          '
          'SectionName: The name of the current section (ex: Jones).
          'ValueName  : The name of the current value   (ex: Email).
          'Value      : The value of [ValueName]        (ex: josh.jones@gmail.com).
          Console.WriteLine(SectionName & ": " & ValueName & " = " & Value)
      Next
  Next
  ```
- Adding everything to a [**`TreeView`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx), where the node's [**`Tag` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) is the value:

  ```
  Dim IniContents As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) = IniParser.ParseFile("C:\path\to\your\file\here.ini")

  For Each SectionName As String In IniContents.Keys
      Dim TopNode As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(SectionName)
      Dim Section As Dictionary(Of String, String) = IniContents(SectionName)

      For Each ValueName As String In Section.Keys
          TopNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(ValueName) With {.Tag = Section(ValueName)})
      Next
  Next
  ```

---

### Screenshot of the TreeView example

[image: TreeView example]

---

### Regex pattern explanation

- `SectionRegex`:

  ```
  \[(?<section>[^\n\[\]]+)\]\n*(?<valuelist>(.(?!\[[^\n\[\]]+\]))*)

  \[                         => Match '['.
  (?<section>                => Start of match group "section".
      [^                     => Match any character...
          \n\[\]             => ...that is not '[', ']' or a new line...
      ]+                     => ...and match this one or more times.
  )                          => End of match group "section".
  \]                         => Match ']'.
  \n*                        => Match zero or more new lines
  (?<valuelist>              => Start of match group "valuelist".
      (                      => Start of unnamed match group.
          .                  => Match any character...
          (?!                => ...that is not followed by...
              \[[^\n\[\]]+\] => ...a section...
          )
      )*                     => ...and match this zero or more times.
  )                          => End of match group "valuelist".
  ```
- `ValueRegex`:

  ```
  (?<valuename>[^=\n]+)=(?<value>[^\n]*)

  (?<valuename>              => Start of match group "valuename".
      [^=\n]+                => Match one or more characters that are not '=' or a new line.
  )                          => End of match group "valuename".
  =                          => Match '='.
  (?<value>                  => Start of match group "value".
      [^\n]*                 => Match zero or more characters that are not a new line.
  )                          => End of match group "value".
  ```

Comment: Thanks, Vincent, for your help.  I tried using your code, but I got errors back.  I'm so new to VB that I don't know if (1) I'm assembling the pieces of code you provided incorrectly or (2) maybe its not VB.net, but VB.

Comment: @AlF. : What errors are you getting? Do you think you could provide screenshots of some of them? -- To find out whether it is VB or VB.NET I need to know what program you are coding in. If you're using Visual Studio then it's VB.NET.

Comment: So all values are strings, even if they are bool or integer. One would cast.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle : All values are strings, yes. This was built to be able to quickly read an INI file. Identifying every type by trying to parse them until one succeeds or not isn't efficient and would slow down the parsing process. It would also require you to store the values in a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` instead, in which case you would have to check the type of each value before using it. It is better to keep them as strings and instead try to parse them when you're actually going to use them and expect them to be of a certain type.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle : For instance, if you expect one of them to be an Integer you'd try parsing it via [**`Integer.TryParse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) when you're going to use the value. Here's an example: https://pastebin.com/GM3KRdwP

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(iniPath)
    Dim user As String = "Jones"
    Dim data As String = "Project"

    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        If a(i) = "[" + user + "]" Then
            For j = i To 1000
                If a(j).Contains(data) Then TextBox1.Text = a(j).Replace(data + "=", "") : Exit For
            Next
            Exit for
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A few notes for you: **1)** No need to split the lines on your own, there's the [**`File.ReadAllLines()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx). -- **2)** Why are you looping to 1000 and not just `a.Length - 1` or `a.GetUpperBound(0)`?

Comment: Exact. You're right Vncent. I forgot that "ReadAllLines" exists, and "a.length-1" is more accurately but add "-1-i". But seeing the ini example file, I felt that 1000 was fine too, and it could be more readable.. I edit the post

Comment: But 1000 is static, whereas `a.Length - 1` is dynamic. What if the file he is reading is over 1001 lines? -- I don't think 100 is more readable, but aside from that it do cause more confusion. :)

Comment: I'm using Visual Basic, not VB.net.