# Using Visual Basic to read a Unicode INI file

Tags: vb.net

Reading INI values from a Unicode INI document with Visual Basic.

I thought that this was correct:

```
Private Class NativeMethods
    ' AJT 2014.11.28 Use the unicode function !!!
    <DllImport("kernel32", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Shared Function WritePrivateProfileString(section As String, key As String, val As String, filePath As String) As Boolean
    End Function

    ' AJT 2014.11.28 Use the unicode function !!!
    <DllImport("kernel32", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(section As String, key As String, def As String, retVal As StringBuilder, size As Integer, filePath As String) As Integer
    End Function
End Class
```

But I am getting question marks when reading Russian data from the INI file.

Then I stumbled over [this](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/file/pprofilebasic.htm) which defines:

> ```
> Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString _
>    Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
>   (ByVal lpSectionName As String, _
>    ByVal lpKeyName As Any, _
>    ByVal lpDefault As String, _
>    ByVal lpbuffurnedString As String, _
>    ByVal nBuffSize As Long, _
>    ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
> ```

I noticed they used `GetPrivateProfileStringA` which makes me think I might need to use `GetPrivateProfileStringW` but now I am confused, as I am using:

```
<DllImport("kernel32", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
```

Please help.

Comment: This is strictly a legacy api, retained to reproduce Windows v3 behavior.  It doesn't know beans about text encoding, it always assumes that the text in the file uses the default system code page.  Hardly the only problem, blowing 50 msec on reading a single setting is pretty hard to hide as well.  Don't use it.

Comment: As an alternative to the `GetPrivateProfileString()` method I've written a pure .NET solution that utilizes Regex to parse an INI. You can load it either from a file or from a string, thus giving you the option specify encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44096742 (right now it supports only reading an INI, but adapting it to write as well isn't very complicated)

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks. I just added a query to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you've provided predates .NET.  What you're looking at (the `Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA"` syntax) is in fact the old way of importing unmanaged types and so on in `VB6`, etc.  This syntax will still work in VB.NET, but it is superseded by the `DllImport` functionality.  If using this older way of doing things, you are correct in that you would need to specify `"GetPrivateProfileStringW"` rather than `"GetPrivateProfileStringA"`.

With regards to the problem you're experiencing, Russian characters may not be the actual cause of your problem; it may be that you are simply getting junk data back.  This can happen if the parameters for your `DllImport` method are not defined using the correct types for one or more of the parameters.

Try taking a look at the following links.  The PInvoke website usually contains useful information on how to correctly define the method signatures:
https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getprivateprofilestring
https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writeprivateprofilestring

For the sake of completeness, I've added these definitions below (copied directly from the links above, although I confess I have not tested them myself). 
 If you are still having difficulty with this, it may be worth updating your answer with an example of the INI file content you are trying to read.

GetPrivateProfileString():

```
DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Private Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal lpAppName As String, _
                        ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
                        ByVal lpDefault As String, _
                        ByVal lpReturnedString As StringBuilder, _
                        ByVal nSize As Integer, _
                        ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
End Function
```

WritePrivateProfileString():

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Private Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal lpAppName As String, _
                        ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
                        ByVal lpDefault As String, _
                        ByVal lpReturnedString As StringBuilder, _
                        ByVal nSize As Integer, _
                        ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. So looking at that webpage how exactly is one telling it to use the Unicode version?

Comment: In your question, setting `CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode` in the `DllImport` attribute tells it to use the unicode version of the function.  My answer is intended to draw attention to the function parameters themselves, as I suspect that's where the problem lies, based on the information currently available in your question.  To avoid confusion however, I've updated my answer to include the setting of the `CharSet` field in the `DllImport` attribute in the examples copied from the PInvoke website.